# jQuery undefined value for some elements

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

I have a response in json format and check some value in my Jquery code its working fine if i check

> dataObject.deviceType==='mobile'

then it's always working fine but for

> dataObject.mobileRedirect

Its always return undefined. Please help if i forgot something. 
My json response is

```
{"successType":11,"notificationMessage":"Sucess message","feed_seourl":"chandoo","deviceType":"mobile","mobileRedirect":"\/mobile\/directories\/#category_id=all&subcategory_id=0&country=India&countryFlag=in.png"}
```

And jquery is

```
if(dataObject.successType === 11 && dataObject.deviceType==='mobile') {
    var mobileuser = dataObject.mobileRedirect;
    if(typeof mobileuser == 'undefined'){
       window.location.href = window.location.protocol+"//"+window.location.host;
    }else {
        window.location.href = window.location.protocol+"//"+window.location.host+dataObject.mobileRedirect;
    }
}
```

Comment: what do you get when you do `console.log(dataObject)`? Can you see the string there? Where do you put the json response to dataObject?

Comment: @Jeff  I have used like this  var dataObject = $.parseJSON(data);
And i checked it with console.log(dataObject.deviceType) it return "mobile"
but for "mobileRedirect" it return "undefined".

Comment: Code works properly, I don't think you're getting dataObject properly.  Did you remember to convert the JSON string to an associated array.

Comment: Just double check the dataObject upon your mobileuser being undefined.